# Ruby / RSpec tests using i18n

Tags: ruby, ios6, rspec, rails-i18n

I am executing tests for my iOS app using rspec i.e. the tests are written in ruby. I can change the language of my app to other languages hence I have kept the ruby test scripts common so that I can run it for any languages.

But how do I run the test for other languages using rspec. I am new to rspec/ruby area and need some help/info about how i18n is handled for rspec testing. How do I check what language my app is in now and the same language I want to run the tests in.

Please suggest.